# How do I register the data held in the session in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session, sql-insert

I am a new student interested in Php. 
    I'm also trying to make a project where we can order online to improve my talent. There is a point where I have a problem and I will share the following codes. I can add items to the shopping cart using the Session and store them in the session directory. After that, I need to save all the products added to this shopping card to the database after I press the "Check out" button. But I do not know how to record the data held in the Session in bulk to the database. In the following code snippets I can display all of the data held in the session (ie all of the added products) with print_r. But how do I register them in the database. 
    I will be very happy if you help me. I wish you a good day.

[My Web Page Ss](https://image.ibb.co/ffV7ho/Ekran_G_r_nt_s_113.png)

[The error I got.](https://image.ibb.co/hM0jTT/Ekran_G_r_nt_s_114.png)

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'dbconnect.php';
?>

<?php require('header.php'); ?>

<?php require('menu.php'); ?>


    <h1 style="text-align: center; color: blue;">Sepetim</h1>
    <div>
    <table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
    <th class="cart">Ürün İsmi</th>
    <th class="cart">Miktar</th>
    <th class="cart">Fiyat Detayları</th>
    <th class="cart">Sipariş Toplamı</th>
    <th class="cart">Sil</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $total = 0;

    //If have something in the cart. Display it.
    if(!empty($_SESSION["cart"]))
    {

        foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $keys => $values)
        {
            ?>
            <tr class="cart">
            <td style="background-color: #d3dcf2"><?php echo $values["item_name"]; ?></td>
            <td class="cart"><?php echo $values["item_quantity"] ?></td>
            <td class="cart"><?php echo $values["product_price"]; ?> ₺</td>
            <td class="cart"><?php echo number_format($values["item_quantity"] * $values["product_price"], 2); ?> ₺</td>
            <td class="cart"><a id="delete" href="shop.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $values["product_id"]; ?>"><span> X</span></a></td>
            </tr>
            <?php 
            $total = $total + ($values["item_quantity"] * $values["product_price"]);
        }

    } 
    ?>
    </table>
    </div>
    <center>
    <div>
        <?php 
        echo "<br>";
        //products with basket added.
        echo "<b>Added products </b><br>";
        print_r(array_values($_SESSION["cart"]));

         echo "<br><br> <b>Array keys</b><br>";
        $column=implode("," , array_keys($_SESSION["cart"][0]));
        echo "$column";

        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br><br> <b>Array values</b><br>";
        $values=implode(",",array_values($_SESSION["cart"][0]));
        echo "$values";
        echo "<br><br>";

        echo "<b>Count in Array</b><br>";
        $count=count($_SESSION["cart"]);
        echo $count;

        echo "<br><br>";

        //Insert Database
        if(!empty($_SESSION["cart"]))
        {
          foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $keys => $values){

            $product_id=$values["product_id"];
            $item_name=$values["item_name"];
            $quantity=$values["item_quantity"];
            $product_price=$values["product_price"];
            $pro_sum=$values["item_quantity"] * $values["product_price"];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO order (product_id,item_name,quantity,product_price,pro_sum,total) 
            VALUES ($product_id,'$item_name',$quantity,$product_price,$pro_sum,$total)";

            if( $DBcon -> query($sql) === TRUE){
                echo "New record created succesfully.";
             }else{
                echo "Error : " . $sql . "<br>" . $DBcon->error;
            }

          }
        }


        echo "<br><br>";

        echo "<br><br>";

         ?>
        <p><u>Ürün toplamı: </u><?php echo number_format($total,2); ?> ₺</p>
        <p><u>Vergiler ve Ücretler : </u><?php echo number_format($total*0.18); ?> ₺</p>
        <h3>Toplam: <?php echo number_format($total*1.18); ?> ₺</h3>
        <h4><a id="checkout" href="checkout.php"> Siparişi Tamamla</a></h4>
    </div>
    </center>







<?php require('footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try yours I get a mistake like this. =>>>
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected" '$ Product_id.' '(T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) C: \ xamp \ htdocs \ Smart-Cafe \ Smart Cafe codes \ yourcart.php on line 83=>>> 
line 83 : $sql = "INSERT INTO order (product_id,item_name,quantity,product_price,pro_sum,total) 
            VALUES ("'.$product_id.'","'.$item_name.'","'.$quantity.'","'.$product_price.'","'.$pro_sum.'","'.$total.'")";

Comment: Ohhh..First single quote then double quote.
$productid = mysql_real_escape_string($values['product_id']);. And enclose every variable like this (mixed double and single quote both). I hope I helps you much. '".$productid."'

Comment: @Kuldeep No. Use placeholder values. Don't do that. Especially don't use the deleted `mysql_query` family of functions.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== true`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant.

Comment: Consider using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to solve problems like this. With those you have patterns you could follow for organizing your code into proper model, view and controller contexts. What you have here is a confused stew of concerns, with HTML, PHP, SQL, and JavaScript all jumbled together. Frameworks come in many forms from really lean like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to exceptionally full-featured like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) and many spots in between.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for yours helping. I solved my problem like this =>>> $sql="INSERT INTO `order` (`order_id`, `product_id`, `item_name`, `quantity`, `product_price`, `pro_sum`, `total`) VALUES (NULL, '".$product_id."', '".$item_name."', '".$quantity."', '".$product_price."', '".$pro_sum."', '".$total."')"; . Have a good days.